# custom collectionViewCell's selectedBackgroundView with rounded corners

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uibezierpath

I'm trying to create a custom **selectedBackgroundView** for my collectionView cell. I subclassed the UIView and this is my drawRect implementation:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 5.0)
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 5
        let color = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
        color.setStroke()

        UIColor(red:0.529, green:0.808, blue:0.922, alpha:1).setFill()
        bezierPath.fill()
        bezierPath.stroke()
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }
```

The following image depicts what I get when the cell is selected.

[image]

As you can see, I'm getting this ugly black corners. I want the black corners to be fully transparent. How can I acchieve that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to call super.drawRect(rect) as the first method, and setting the background color to UIColor.clearColor.

Comment: I added  super.drawRect(rect)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor(), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the view's layer's cornerRadius to 5.

> self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

And set the view's clipsToBounds property to true.

> self.view.clipsToBounds = true;

Comment: I set what you said but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Try also setting self.view.clipsToBounds = true, in addition to setting the layer corner radius to 5.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help.

Comment: Looks like I need to set cornerRadius and clipsToBounds directly in drawRect: method. This works. Suprisingly, awakeFromNib is not the right place.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I have actually never used awakeFromNib so I'm not sure why that's the case. Usually when I want to load a view from a nib, I have a UIView subclass that I implement in code, and that class, in its constructor, loads the nib and adds it to itself as a subview. In this case, I would set those properties on the in-code wrapper UIView class, in its constructor. Or if I'm using a ViewController, then I would override its ViewDidLoad method and do it there.

Comment: I added a print method in awakeFromNib but was never executed. I think that when creating a view entirely in code using drawRect, there is no need for awakeFromNib to be called at all.